# Working with production.log rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got my production log file working. But wanted to get some suggestions onto how to work with it. I currently look at it view console and doing either

```
tail log/*
tail -f log/production.log
```

to look at it. I would like to either 1. find a better way to be able to look at the logs and perhaps with colors. 2. Can the production log file be outputted in a view where an admin user can view it?

Lastly, is there a gem that's great for emailing me when an error occurred and what the error was / how do you currently keep track of when errors happening in production?

Thanks!

Comment: I use honeybadger for errors.

Comment: Yep, and there is new relic too.

Comment: [LogEntries](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) is good for Heroku-based apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just having a nicer alternative to `tail` which shows the colours instead of those ESC[… codes, try `less -R production.log`.  If you want to follow the end of the file like `tail -f`, use:

```
less -R +F production.log
```

There's nothing built-in for getting the log into a view as far as I know, but I suppose you could write a controller which shows (some of) the log in a view.  Make sure it's secure with authentication though; you don't want to be exposing your log to the internet!  Using an external service should remove this concern and it will have a load of other features.  For example, I haven't tried papertrail (https://papertrailapp.com) but it's been on my to-try list for a while.  It looks good and they're free for up to 100MB of logs a month.  I've used airbrake (https://airbrake.io/) in the past for exception notifications but I don't think they have a free tier - just a free trial.

Comment: If you really want to, as far as I know you could just use standard ruby to read the file; just use the name "#{Rails.root}/log/production.log".  You'd probably want to use tail (perhaps using a file-tail gem, or calling out to tail directly) on it to get the last however-many-lines as it could be large.  However, I've never tried displaying logs through the app itself.  I'd recommend a third-party service for the reasons I mentioned.